# munmap anonymous shared memory in forked child

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory, signal-handling

i'd like to know if it is necessary (or advisable) to unmap shared memory (using `munmap`) in child created via `fork`, if the memory was obtained in the parent, before the fork, using `mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED,...)` and will also be unmapped in the parent, which will `wait` for the child.
Also i would like to know whether it is necessary (or advisable) to close a file in the child, if the file was opened in the parent (before the fork, using `fopen`) and will be closed in the parent after the child terminates.

I am thinking of using a user-defined signal and a signal handler in which the parent will wait for child processes, and then the process -- wheter it is the parent or not -- will close the file and unmap the memory. This signal will be sent to all processes in the group from a process, in which an error occurred (i do not want to pass return values).

Actually it is a bit more complex, but i only want to know whether i need to do this:

```
void sig_handler() {
    if (getpid() == getpgrp()) // parent
        while (proc_count--)
            wait(NULL); // signal has already been sent to all child processes
    // every single process will do this:
    fclose(memory->file);
    munmap(memory, size);
    exit(123);
}
```

or it is *completely* OK to do this:

```
void sig_handler() {
    if (getpid() == getpgrp()) {
        while (proc_count--)
            wait(NULL);
        fclose(memory->file);
        munmap(memory, size);
    }
    exit(123);
}
```

I have tried closing the file in one child process; it seemed to have no effect in other processes -- i assume the fd table is copied on fork. Is there a way to make it shared between processes? (Probably not, i suspect)

Any answer is appreciated. Thank you.

PS. Is there a reason why can't i start my question with a greeting (eg. Hello) ?

Comment: RE your PS: See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Read this:  http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal  Pay attention to the list of async-signal-safe functions about halfway down the page.  Those are the **only** functions that are safe to call in a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks. 
(it says "8 more to go" so i have to write some more)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to exit the process, there's no point in calling `munmap()`.  The memory will be unmapped for that process when the process exits.

`fclose()` will flush any buffers holding unwritten data to the file.  In all processes - the parent and the child.  Whether or not you want that is up to you.

`exit()` implicitly flushes all buffers.  `_exit()` does not flush buffers or call any other exit handlers.

Comment: So if i understand correctly i need to call neither fclose nor munmap if i call exit? Also, i use semaphores and these need to be destroyed as well, as far as i know. What could possibly happen, or what would be the worst case, if i tried to do this in in the signal handler? (Of course i would only destroy a semaphore once)
Anyways, i tried to run the program through valgrind. No leaks are possible, but is there a way, or a tool similar to valgrind, to detect whether the process has explicitly called fclose prior to exiting?

Comment: It depends.  If you `fork()` a child process, the child gets a copy of the entire address space of the parent.  If the parent has unwritten data in a file buffer, so does the child.  If you call `fclose()` on that file, the data in the buffer will be written to the file - and calling `exit()` does that implicitly.  In both the child AND the parent process.  And it depends on what kind of semaphores you are using.  SysV semaphores obtained with `semget()`, POSIX semaphores (`sem_t mySem; sem_init(&mySem 0 0);`)?  In general, POSIX semaphores get destroyed when the process(s) using them exit.

Comment: I am using anonymous POSIX semaphores; from `man sem_destroy`:
    "An unnamed semaphore should be destroyed with sem_destroy() before  the  memory  in  which it is located is deallocated. Failure to do this can result in resource leaks on some implementations."

Comment: Just be careful about which process(es) call `sem_destroy()` if you called `sem_init()` to initialize the semaphore as a process-shared semaphore (`sem_init(&mySem,1,0)`) and it's still in use by other processes.

Comment: The course of operation would be this: parent forks child A and B, each of them forking some more processes. In these grand-children processes, the semaphores will be waited on. If an error occurs, eg. in process B, while forking, and A has already forked its children, B will do `killpg(getpgrp(), SIGUSR1)`, and children waiting on semaphores will be interrupted and they will exit. A and B will wait for their children and the main parent will wait for A and B, then destroy the semaphores (after the waiting processes have exited). Is this OK?

Comment: Sounds well-thought-out.  The details of the implementation will obviously matter.